# Scala: Transforming List of Strings containing long descriptions to list of strings containing only last sentences

Tags: scala

I have a List[String], for example:

```
val test=List("this is, an extremely long sentence. Check; But. I want this sentence.",
  "Another. extremely. long. (for eg. description). But I want this sentence.",
    ..)
```

I want the result to be like:

```
List("I want this sentence", "But I want this sentence"..)
```

I tried few approaches but didn't work

> test.map(x=>x.split(".").reverse.head)
>   test.map(x=>x.split(".").last)

Comment: Your approaches work if you change your split into a Char instead of a String, ie `test.map(x=>x.split('.').reverse.head)` and `test.map(x=>x.split('.').last)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

```
test.reverse.head.split("\\.").last
```

To handle any `Exception`

```
Try(List[String]().reverse.head.split("\\.").last).getOrElse("YOUR_DEFAULT_STRING")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` over you `List`, `split` each `String` and then take the last element. Try the below code.

```
val list = List("this is, an extremely long sentence. Check; But. I want this sentence.",
  "Another. extremely. long. (for eg. description). But I want this sentence.")

list.map(_.split("\\.").last.trim)
```

It will give you

```
List(I want this sentence, But I want this sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test.map (_.split("\\.").last)
```

Split takes a regular expression, and in such, the dot stands for every character, so you have to mask it.

Maybe you want to include question marks and bangs:

```
test.map (_.split("[!?.]").last)
```

and trim surrounding whitespace:

```
test.map (_.split("[!?.]").last.trim).
```

The `reverse.head` would have been a good idea, if there wasn't the `last`:

```
scala>     test.map (_.split("[!?.]").reverse.head.trim)
res138: List[String] = List(I want this sentence, But I want this sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways:

**For each string in your original list: split by `.`, reverse the list, take the first value**

```
test.map(_.split('.').reverse.headOption)
// List(Some( I want this sentence), Some( But I want this sentence))
```

`.headOption` results in `Some("string")` or `None`, and you can do something like a `.getOrElse("no valid string found")` on it. You can trim the unwanted whitespace if you want.

---

**Regex match**

```
test.map { sentence =>
  val regex = ".*\\.\\s*([^.]*)\\.$".r
  val regex(value) = sentence
  value
}
```

This will fetch any string at the end of a longer string which is preceded by a full stop and a space and followed by a full stop. You can modify the regex to change the exact rules of the regex, and I recommend playing around with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) if you fancy learning more regex. It's very good.

This solution is better for more complicated examples and requirements, but it's worth keeping in mind. If you are worried that the regex might not match, you can do something like checking if the regex matches before extracting it:

```
test.map { sentence =>
  val regexString = ".*\\.\\s*([^.]*)\\.$"
  val regex = regexString.r
  if(sentence.matches(regexString)) {
    val regex(value) = sentence
    value
  } else ""
}
```

---

**Take the last after splitting the string by `.`**

```
test.map(_.split('.').map(_.trim).lastOption)
```